# How do you animate a change in a view's padding?

Tags: android, animation, view, viewgroup

I want to animate the change in the padding of a view. The resting place of the translation animation is the same as the padding I want to apply.

```
TranslateAnimation moveleft = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.ABSOLUTE, 0.0f,
                    Animation.ABSOLUTE, PADDING, Animation.ABSOLUTE,
                    0.0f, Animation.ABSOLUTE, 0.0f);

moveLeft.setDuration(500);
moveLeft.setFillAfter(true);
```

This starts the view's animation then sets the padding. This doesn't exactly work because it cause a graphical glitch.

```
v.startAnimation(moveleft);   
v.setPadding(PADDING, 0, 0,0);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of setting your padding right away, why not try an animation listener to set the padding after the animation has completed?

```
v.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
    ...
    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(){
        v.setPadding(PADDING, 0, 0,0);
    }
    ...
});
v.startAnimation(moveleft);
```

Comment: I tried this implementation before but it still resulted is a similar graphic glitch. However, I found a way to fix it. I called `.clearAnimation()` on the animated view before I set the padding. I assumed the code in the `.onAnimationEnd()` ran after the animation had ended. That doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: In addition I removed `.setFillAfter()`.

Answer (score 58):

Use ValueAnimator, its really simple and unclutter

say,
     we have to change right padding to _20dp where as left, top and bottom padding are _6dp, _6dp and 0 respectively.

`ofInt()` is varagrs type. the value we have to animate is pass in it as KeyValue pair (arg1 = current value, arg2 = target value,............)

Here we go,

```
ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(view.getPaddingRight(), _20dp);
animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator){
        view.setPadding(_6dp, _6dp, (Integer) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue(), 0);
    }
});
animator.setDuration(200);
animator.start();
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to animate `setPadding` in Kotlin:

```
private fun setPaddingWithAnimation() {

    val paddingDp: Int = 20

    val density: Float = requireActivity().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density

    val paddingPixel: Int = (paddingDp * density).toInt()

    val animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(recyclerItems.paddingRight, paddingPixel)

    animator.addUpdateListener { valueAnimator -> binding.recyclerHealthTips.recyclerHealthTips.setPadding(
                paddingPixel, 0, valueAnimator.animatedValue as Int, 0) }
        
    animator.duration = 500
    animator.start()
}
```